# Write an arithmetic expression in Racket

Tags: racket

Expression 3^2 + 6 * (6 - 10) / 3
need to write an proper arithmetic expression

I have tried
(/ ( * ( + (* 3 2 ) 6)(- 6 10)) 3)

Comment: 3^2 is not the same as `(* 3 2)`

Comment: You wrote (((3 * 2) + 6) * (6 - 10)) / 3

Answer (score 1):

There are at least a couple of problems.

- The double left parentheses. That means "make a function call on the result returned from another function". In this case, the code tries to execute a function call on the result of the addition.
- '3' is not a function. A left parenthesis before the `3` (near the addition) means you want to call the function `3`, but there is no such function. As you know, `3` is a number, not a function.

Do you know what the answer is supposed to be?

Maybe use DrRacket to work through this. It is very easy to use interactively and will keep pointing out errors until there are none.

**Update**: Well, since your edit, those errors have been fixed. Now you need to pay attention to @kluvin's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are confusing the operator precedence, it's easier if you parenthesize the expression first.

```
3^2 + 6 * (6 - 10) / 3

(3^2 + ((6 * (6 - 10)) / 3))

(+
 (square 3)
 (/
  (*
   6
   (- 6 10))
  3))
```

Or, if you want:

```lisp
(+
 (square 3)
 (*
  6
  (/
   (- 6 10)
   3)))
```

Comment: Expression is  3^2 + 6 * (6 - 10) / 3
need to write it on racket